# Django parallel testing: Test processes incorrectly accessing test databases

Tags: python, django, testing

I have a Django 3.0.8 project running locally, connected to a local **PostgreSQL** database (`postgres:///myapp`). When I run the `python manage.py test`, my unit tests run fine; a test database called `test_myapp` automatically gets created, and it's correctly accessed.

However, when I run `python manage.py test --parallel 8`, the test fails. I see that 8 cloned databases are correctly generated (`test_myapp_1`, `test_myapp_2`,..., `test_myapp_8`), but I get errors like these:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "myapp_3" does not exist
```

It appears that for parallel tests, databases are accessed incorrectly (trying to access the database `myapp_N` rather than `test_myapp_N`). I'm trying to figure out if my local config has issues, but this is all I have in my base config:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': env.db('DATABASE_URL', default='postgres:///myapp'),
}
DATABASES['default']['ATOMIC_REQUESTS'] = True
```

Why are my parallel tests processes not accessing their respective cloned test databases correctly?

Comment: Could you share more on how you have configured your database?
`from django.conf import settings;print(settings.DATABASES)`

Comment: @AmirHeshmati here is the result of `print(settings.DATABASES)`:

Comment: {
   "default":{
      "NAME":"skale",
      "USER":"",
      "PASSWORD":"",
      "HOST":"",
      "PORT":"",
      "ENGINE":"django.db.backends.postgresql",
      "ATOMIC_REQUESTS":True,
      "AUTOCOMMIT":True,
      "CONN_MAX_AGE":0,
      "OPTIONS":{
         "fallback_application_name":"django_shell"
      },
      "TIME_ZONE":"None",
      "TEST":{
         "CHARSET":"None",
         "COLLATION":"None",
         "NAME":"None",
         "MIRROR":"None"
      }
   }
}

Comment: I am having the same issue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that worked for me is to explicitly specify the test database name in `settings.py`, e.g.,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
        'TEST': {
            # Avoid naming it the same as your original database name. 
            # Otherwise, it will be used while testing (and even may get deleted).
            'NAME': 'name_of_your_choice',
        },
    },
    ...
}
```

If you are using [multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/multi-db/#multiple-databases), you may need to do it for all of them.

Answer (score -1):

for using the PostgreSQL database on your Django project you can configure your database the same.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": 'Table_name',
        "USER": 'user_name',
        "PASSWORD": 'password',
        "HOST": 'localhost', # or 127.0.0.1
        "PORT": '5432', #5432 is the default PostgreSQL port if you change it must change this port
    }
}
```

and for setting multiple databases on your Django project, you can see [this page](https://blog.devgenius.io/multiple-databases-in-django-925ca821bdd0) and use it.